# laravel blade use vueJs without build and components vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-vite

I have an application that is based on larvel blades.
In the blades I want to use vueJs3 without build, but to insert vue components.

I'm getting an error in the console: **Uncaught ReferenceError: createApp is not defined**

---

I followed these steps:

1. npm install
2. npm install vue
3. npm install vue-loader
4. npm i @vitejs/plugin-vue
5. in the **vite.config.js** file I added

   ```js
   import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

   export default {
     plugins: [vue()]
   }
   ```
6. I created the file **example.vue**
7. in the **app.js** file I added

   ```js
   import { createApp } from "vue";
   import example from "./example.vue";
   ```
8. npm run dev

---

I use:

1. Laravel 9.19
2. vite 2.9.11
3. vueJs 3
4. vue-loader 17.0.0

---

My files:

**vite.config.js**

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
        ]),
    ],
});
```

**resources/js/app.js**

```js
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from "vue";
import example from "./example.vue";
```

**welcome.blade**

```html
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <example/>
  </div>
  @vite('resources/js/app.js')
</body>

<script>
  var app = createApp({
      components: {
         example
      },
      data() {
          return {
             message: "Hello world"
          }
      }
  })
  
  app.mount("#app")
</script>
```

Comment: You need to move the code from <script> into your app.js

Comment: is not a solution, I have a lot of blades that have <script> and vueJs code

Comment: You have a misunderstanding of how vue and builds work you need all your vue code to be inside javascript not in your blade files as vite needs to build all the code.